# Form a python dictionary based on pattern matched keys and values in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary with a file containing text based on a matched pattern. Lines containing `key_str` should become keys and subsequent lines should become values associated with those keys in the dictionary.

File:

```
ml1
/core
/home

ml2
/var
/home
/lib

cpuml1
/home
/root
/raid
```

Expected Output

```
my_dict: {ml1: ['/core','/home'], ml2: ['/var','/home','/lib'], cpuml1: ['/home','/root','/raid']}
```

Code:

```
d = {}
key_str = "ml"
val_str = ""
key_list = []
val_list = []
with open(homedir+'/backup/file2dict.result') as file2dict:
    for line in file2dict:
        words=line.split()
        for aWord in words:
            if key_str in aWord:
                key_list.append(aWord)
                print(key_list)
            else:
                val_list.append(aWord)
    print("this is formed dictionary", d)
```

Comment: Why does `ml2` have `['/core','/home']` rather than `['/var','/home', '/lib']`?

Comment: fixed output and updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you encounter a new key, add existing val_list to last key and wipe val_list.

```
key_str = "ml"
val_str = ""
val_list = []
key = ''
d = {}
with open(homedir + '/backup/file2dict.result') as file2dict:
    for line in file2dict:
        words = line.split()
        for aWord in words:
            if key_str in aWord:
                if key:
                    d[key] = val_list
                    val_list = []
                    key = aWord
                else:
                    key = aWord
            else:
                val_list.append(aWord)
    d[key] = val_list

    print("this is formed dictionary", d)
```

Comment: Thanks works like charm but for only two keys that begin with `ml`, however key is not catching `cpuml1` and this is being skipped. any hint? why if `ml` in middle of string is being skipped?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed a step, forgot to add the last key to the dictionary. I edited it to fix it.

Comment: any hint why my question got -1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that input format is correct, with double linefeeds between each block, each block starting with a key name, each following line in a block being a value for that key, and each key being unique in the file, as well as assuming that you meant `['/var','/home', '/lib']` for the `ml2` key, then the result can be created with a comprehension:

```
with open(file) as f:
    result = {key:lst for key, *lst in (block.split('\n') for block in f.read().split('\n\n'))}
```

Testing with a multiline string instead of a file:

```
>>> s = '''ml1
... /core
... /home
...
... ml2
... /var
... /home
... /lib
...
... cpuml1
... /home
... /root
... /raid'''
>>> {key:lst for key, *lst in (block.split('\n') for block in s.split('\n\n'))}
{'ml1': ['/core', '/home'], 'ml2': ['/var', '/home', '/lib'], 'cpuml1': ['/home', '/root', '/raid']}
```

Comment: Indeed, your code works for the defined log file BUT my main requirement is to FORM keys and values based on pattern match. yes you may consider there are no duplicates of keys.

Comment: Also, would be a favor if you can please explain your logic of picking keys. what is lst and *lst?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
keystr="ml"
k=''
d = {}
with open ("testp.txt") as file2dict:
    for line in file2dict:
        li = line.strip()
        # This uses your keystr, but you could say if not line.startswith("/"):
        if keystr in li:  
            k = li
        elif li and k:
            d[k] = d.get(k,[]) + [li]
        
print(d)
```

Comment: any reason for not using `d.setdefault` here?

Comment: Nope, just my out of date  python2.x legacy.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer, that `d[k] = d.get(k,[]) + [li]` can be replaced with `d.setdefault(k, []).append(li)`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code:

```py
key_str = "ml"
result = {}
curr_key = None
with open('file2dict.result', 'r') as file2dict:
    for line in filter(lambda l: l != '', map(str.strip, file2dict)):
        if key_str in line:
            curr_key = line
            result[curr_key] = []
        elif curr_key is not None:
            result[curr_key].append(line)
        else:
            print("Value without a key: {}".format(line))
```

Here `filter(lambda l: l != '', map(str.strip, file2dict))` id used to filter out empty lines; moreover you can use a `dict` (`result`) to collect lines.

If you cannot have keys without any following valid line in your input file (or if you want to skip them), you can use `setdefault` for your dict:

```py
key_str = "ml"
result = {}
curr_key = None
with open('file2dict.result', 'r') as file2dict:
    for line in filter(lambda l: l != '', map(str.strip, file2dict)):
        if key_str in line:
            curr_key = line
        elif curr_key is not None:
            result.setdefault(curr_key, []).append(line)
        else:
            print("Value without a key: {}".format(line))
```

Comment: using lamda when we are already getting non empty lines then what is the purpose of `map(str.strip, file2dic)` ?

Comment: `strip` removes empty spaces at the beginning and end of a line; after this trim, the line can result empty (think about a line composed of only white spaces), so  `filter` is used to skip these lines.